# ¿Cómo se puede validar que un String no sea un numero en python?

Tags: python, variables

¿hay alguna forma de validar un campo string para que no se le puedan meter números?
He estado buscando información al respecto, pero todo lo que he encontrado no me contempla que pueda meter un numero, ya sea entero o float

Gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Eso es con la funcion input o en una interfaz grafica como Tkinter???

Comment: `"String, holas".isalpha()`

Comment: @Christian me sirve, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

El resultado es el siguiente:

```
if not palabra.isalpha():
            logging.info("El valor debe de ser una palabra")
```

Answer (score 1):

Una manera de chequear que un ingreso no sea interpretable como valor numérico es tratar de convertirlo a `float`. Si eso falla, tiene que ser una cadena

```
def ingresar_cadena(texto):
    try:
        while True:
            ingreso = input(texto)
            float(ingreso)
    except ValueError:
        pass
    return ingreso
```

Esta función recibe un texto y luego pide al usuario un ingreso en un ciclo infinito.

La única manera de romper el ciclo es que lo ingresado no sea numérico.

Al salir, retorna la cadena ingresada.

Comment: Muy bueno, lo había intentado hacer con int(ingreso), pero no contempla los números que no sean enteros. Muchas gracias